# Why is `duplicable?` defined the way it is?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I come across this in Rails source code:

```
class Object
  def duplicable?
    true
  end
end

class NilClass
  begin
    nil.dup
  rescue TypeError    
    def duplicable?
      false
    end
  end
end
```

With this code, even after `dup` is removed from an object, that object responds to `duplicable?` with `true`.

I think it can be rewritten to a simpler code like:

```
class Object
  def duplicable?
    repond_to?(:dup)
  end
end
```

What is the merit of defining `duplicable?` using `begin`...`rescue`?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> What is the merit of defining `duplicable?` using `begin`...`rescue`?

Ruby before 2.4 raised a TypeError when attempting to `nil.dup`:

```
$ rbenv local 2.3.0

$ ruby --version
ruby 2.3.0p0 (2015-12-25 revision 53290) [x86_64-darwin15]

$ ruby -e 'p nil.dup'
-e:1:in `dup': can't dup NilClass (TypeError)
    from -e:1:in `<main>'
```

Starting with Ruby 2.4, `nil.dup` just returns itself:

```
$ rbenv local 2.4.0

$ ruby --version
ruby 2.4.0p0 (2016-12-24 revision 57164) [x86_64-darwin15]

$ ruby -e 'p nil.dup'
nil
```

Putting the method definition inside `rescue` ensures that the method is only defined for Ruby versions which raise the `TypeError`.

> I think it can be rewritten to a simpler code like: [...]

Simply checking whether the receiver responds to `dup` doesn't work, because `nil` – being an `Object` – *does* respond to `dup`, even in 2.3. The `TypeError` is (was) raised from within `Object#dup`:

```c
VALUE rb_obj_dup(VALUE obj)
{
    VALUE dup;

    if (rb_special_const_p(obj)) {
        rb_raise(rb_eTypeError, "can't dup %s", rb_obj_classname(obj));
    }
    // ...
}
```

Comment: @engineerk this one should be surely marked as the correct answer, not mine. Please amend.

Comment: I might made some mistakes in checkmark and replying. Sorry for being a begginer in stackoverflow.

Comment: @engineerk no worries :-)

Answer (score 3):

`nil` **responds** to `dup` explicitly throwing the `TypeError` (which has, in turn, nothing to do with `NoMethodError`.) [Correction: had responded to `dup` before 2.4, credits go to @Stefan.]

```
NilClass.instance_method(:dup)
#⇒ #<UnboundMethod: NilClass(Kernel)#dup>
```

The goal is to respond to `duplicable?` with `false` *unless* `NilClass#dup` is overwritten by another monkey patcher in the city. [Correction: read “another monkey patcher” as “Matz” :)]

Comment: @Stefan I don’t have a sufficient rep to amend foreign checkmarks :(